# Beginner problem with CodeIgniter REST_Controller

Tags: javascript, api, codeigniter, rest

I'm trying to setup a REST API in Codeigniter following this example: 
http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/working-with-restful-services-in-codeigniter-2/

But before anything, I want to make sure I can invoke the user_get() function with calling

http://mysite.com/myApp/index.php/helloworld/user/id/1/format/json

and I thought the outcome would be a simple "user_get called"

```
  <?php
require("application/libraries/REST_Controller.php");

class Helloworld extends REST_Controller{

    function user_get()
    {
        echo "user_get called";
    }
}
    ?>
```

But instead, I got this error: 
An Error Was Encountered
Unable to load the requested class: format

What was wrong?
Thanks!!

Answer (score 14):

There is also a file called format.php which you have to copy from the REST_Controller package.
That does the magic

Answer (score 1):

import into your codeigniter library, Format.php.
get the file here https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-restserver/blob/master/application/libraries/Format.php

Answer (score 0):

Does it tell you at which line this error happen? It looks like you need to define a class called "format" somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Check this line in file `REST_Controller.php`

```
// This library is bundled with REST_Controller 2.5+, but will eventually be part of CodeIgniter itself
$this->load->library('WHEREDOYOUHAVETHEFILE REST_Controller.php/format');
```